# AHK Change Nvidia Colour Settings

Tags: autohotkey

I want to hotkey nvidia colour profiles. 
There are sliders on the desktop colour page and I have no idea how to macro these. Can anyone offer any assistance?

What i have gleaned from Window Spy over one of the sliders:

**NVIDIA Control Panel**
ahk_class
Afx:00007FF7660C0000:b:0000000000010005:0000000000000006:0000000000690523
ahk_exe nvcplui.exe

Control Under Mouse:
ClassNN:    msctls_trackbar321
Text:
    x: 466  y: 458  w: 188  h: 24
Client: x: 458  y: 407  w: 188  h: 24

Here is the Nvidia Control Panel Page.
[image: Nvidia Control Panel Page]

Each window Control *does* have its own ClassNN;

- Brightness - ClassNN:    msctls_trackbar321
- Contrast   -ClassNN: msctls_trackbar322
- Gamma      -ClassNN: msctls_trackbar323

I want to have a few different profiles. so default is (in order of above)

50%, 50%, 1.00

and an example one i want is

60%, 25%, 2.66

The apply button does not have to be pressed for cahnges to take effect

This might not be possible with AHK, may possibly even need some registry editing.
I have no idea how to edit anything in window controls.
tia

Comment: It's going to require a significant amount of code. 1. What particular controls do you want to manipulate? 2. Does **each** of them have its **own** ClassNN string? If not, it's going to be even more complex.

Answer (score 1):

This controls the volume slider in the Volume mixer on my PC

Windows Spy

Volume Mixer - Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)
ahk_class #32770
ahk_exe SndVol.exe

Below is the control in Spy

ClassNN:    msctls_trackbar325
Text:
    x: 75   y: 205  w: 43   h: 234
Client: x: 70   y: 172  w: 43   h: 234

This raises the control z = trackbar number 325

Run SndVol.exe
WinWaitActive, Volume Mixer - Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio),, 20

z = 325 ; msctls_trackbar = 325

ControlSend,  msctls_trackbar%z%, {Up},  Volume Mixer - Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)

You can send a {Down} to lower the control.

You might be able to send a number to the msctls_trackbar and move the slider to a specific position. 0 being bottom 10, 20 30 etc for a position further up the bar.